# R900 with Discs larger than 4TB

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata, dell-poweredge

***My Hardware***

Dell PowerEdge R900 with LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 1078 (rev 04)

**[R900 Technical Specifications](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/pe_R900_spec_sheet.pdf)**

About Hard Drives it says maximum for 3.5” 2.0TB SATA. 
This is an older server so i am assuming at the time of writing that Technical Specification 2TB might be the largest drive available or that's what they tested with

**What i am doing**

I am adding new storage to my server to while shopping for hard drives i found a 4TB drive which says it is for R900
http://disctech.com/Products/4TB-SAS-Serial-Attached-SCSI-Hard-Drives

***Question***

1. Not looking for opinion whether it might or might not work but from somebody's actual experience
2. please share if they had successfully used drives larger than 2TB in Dell PowerEdge R900

Comment: If it says the maximum is 2TB capacity then that is a technical limitation due to the SATA or RAID controller.The list of HDDs you provided, don't specifically say the support R900, go by the technical specifications. **This comment is not my opinion, it it based on nearly 2 decades working with computer hardware, and a decade of professional experience in the sector** I have no personal experience with the R900, I don't need it, I have experience with computers in general.  SATA controllers have capacity restrictions, if the maximum capacity indicated for the R900 is 2TB, then it must be 2TB.

Comment: you are right, i think i over joyed too quickly , This section has R900 in the list "Example models are: WD4000FYYZ .Hot-swap SAS / Serial Attached SCSI hard drives are commonly used i" --- I think i so badly want to use larger drives

Comment: Some advice.  You don't need to indicate, you don't want an  you don't want our opinion, questions seeking our opinion are not on topic.  So its implied that any answer we give you, should be backed up by experience, an answer to this question would be to point to the specifications of the R900.  I typical don't find questions that, seek our experiences, to be very helpful.  There is a good question, its hidden, but it exists.

Comment: so i have T300s and technical specific for those says maximum 1TB and i am currently using a 5TB disc in it , difference no RAID in T300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it,

I got a 5TB Hard Disk and it would only recognize 2TB out of it

It would have been nice if i can go beyond 2TB